# create-react-app in development mode: setting PUBLIC_URL environment variable results in errors

Tags: nginx, create-react-app

Ive created a React SPA using create-react-app and using nginx to reverse proxy the React app to a URL of the form domain/path. My aim is to hang multiple React components from a single domain.

e.g.

mysite.com/app1
mysite.com/app2
etc

Ive set the the PUBLIC_URL in env in the hope that accessing mysite.com/app1 will route to my React app. Currently not working for a brand new create-react-app with only mods as below.

**.env file**
﻿

```
PORT=3123
PUBLIC_URL='/app1/'
```

**nginx.conf**

```
    location ^~ /app1/sockjs-node {
        proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:3123/sockjs-node;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
    location ^~ /app1/ {
        proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:3123/;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
```

**browser output** is a white screen and the following errors:

```
bundle.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
0.chunk.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
main.chunk.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
manifest.json:1 Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Syntax error.
```

Perhaps im being too simplistic or optimistic but i was hoping that setting the .env PUBLIC_URL append the path /app1/ to all URLs, but its not working.

Any help, insight or advice much appreciated.

Thanks
﻿

Answer (score 0):

fixed this in nginx.conf. all assets and sockets have correct paths.

```
location ^~ /app1/sockjs-node {
    proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:3123/app1/sockjs-node;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
location ^~ /app1/ {
    proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:3123/app1/;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
```